# How to eliminate an array from multi-dimentional array

Tags: ruby

The following gives what I want. `[[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]`

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
b = [[1, 2, 3]]
a - b
=> [[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
```

But the following doesn't

```
b = [1, 2, 3]
a - b
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Now my question is how I can convert an array `[1, 2, 3]` to `[[1, 2, 3]]`?

Or any other way I can do it?

I also tried Array#drop, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you give a reason why I get minus, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [Array#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-delete):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
b = [1, 2, 3]
a.delete b
a #=> [[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
```

To answer your exact question, you can wrap *any* object (even arrays) into an array with:

```
[object]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there something I'm missing about the question? I'm guessing the reason you got downvotes is the simplicity of the answer which implies that you didn't do any research.

```
b = [1,2,3]
[b]
#=> [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [Array#-](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) documentation, it states that

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in other_ary.

so

- when b is `[[1,2,3]]` there is only one element and that is `[1,2,3]`
- when b is `[1,2,3]` there are three elements `1`, `2` and `3` which are not in array `a`

Finally if you have `b = [1,2,3]` you need to provide
`a - [b]`
to get the desired result.